# Drawbacks of using alternate shells such as LiteStep

Tags: windows-7, shell

I Am considering installing LiteStep (http://www.litestep.net/) onto my computer, as I enjoy customization and Desktop Modification and have seen lots of cool themes for litestep. Before I install, though, I was wondering if alternate shells such as LiteStep would interfere with the operation of my Operating System or the applications that run on it. I work with lots of System-Intensive applications; like Photoshop, Premiere, Davinci Resolve... etc. so it would be quite annoying if they didn't run properly.

Somewhat the main reason I thought LiteStep would Interfere with my system is because, according to WikiPedia, it is designed for 9x windows systems, which to my understanding, are 32bit- whereas my computer runs Windows 7 Professional 64bit. Could this not cause instabilities?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried any of these for many years...

But, generally you lose stability and accountability. Some applications will not run correctly, some not at all and some will work just as well as they would on explorer.

Some of these are buggy, have memory leaks, and just do weird things.

For testing, I would use a spare machine, VM or dual boot. If you can certify as good enough for your use, then roll it to your machine.

As for accountability, I think it is important to know that no one will support these Shell replacements, MS, Dell, or whoever else you may rely on will (likely accurately) immediately blame the shell and ask for its removal or for it to be disabled as a first step.

With x64, and Windows 7... [there maybe at least some hope:](http://forums.litestep.info/viewtopic.php?id=316)

Comment: To my understanding LiteStep, while being an alternate shell, still uses Explorer.

Comment: http://www.lsdev.org/doku.php  originally created by Francis Gastellu. LiteStep is a replacement shell for the standard Windows® Explorer shell.

Comment: oh, ok. sorry, i thought wrong ahah